# WooCommerce Order Item Meta Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working to get the meta data from an order that was created by Product Addons. I can get the meta, but am having trouble looping through it correctly.  Here is an example of the returned array:

```
Array ( [414] => Array ( [key] => Attendee First Name 
                         [value] => John 
                         [display_key] => Attendee First Name 
                         [display_value] => John
                       ) 
        [415] => Array ( [key] => Attendee Last Name 
                         [value] => Doe 
                         [display_key] => Attendee Last Name 
                         [display_value] => Doe
                       ) 
      )
```

I have tried the following:

```
<?php 
$formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
$array = json_decode(json_encode($formatted_meta_data), true);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $test = $value['value'];
}
?>
```

This outputs only the 2nd array value, so I get the last name, but can't seem to access the first name. I want to be able to separate first name and last name with something like `$fname = $value['Attendee First Name'];` but I haven't found a way to access that from the array.

Comment: You can use `array_column()` function

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the `array_column()` function as suggested by @MadhurBhaiya along with the `array_combine()` function I was able to get this to work the way I wanted it to.

```
$formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
// create an array of just the keys
$keys = array_column($formatted_meta_data, 'key');
// create an array of just the values
$values = array_column($formatted_meta_data, 'value');
// combine the arrays into a more useful format
$names = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

End Result:

```
Array ( [Attendee First Name] => John [Attendee Last Name] => Doe )
```

Now I can access this easily like this:

```
echo $names['Attendee First Name'].' '.$names['Attendee Last Name'].'<br>';
```

Output:

John Doe

**Discussion**
Yes, I could have just used `array_column()` and then output the values with something like `$values[0]` but there since this is using WooCommerce Product Addons, it is very likely that more fields will be added in the future and I wanted to ensure I only returned the required values.